# Way to load locally developed magento extension

Tags: magento

I am developing a magento extension. After getting help from stackoverflow, I am able to create a package extension which is stored in [magento]/var/connect folder. I noticed that package.xml, myextension.xml and myextension-1.0.0.0.1.tgz files are created therein.

I created another magento instance locally where I want to load that package and test. It's not possible to get my extension verified by magento team and then use it quickly or is it? I copied those package files under /var/connect of the test instance but I cannot see that appear in admin-> system -> magento connect -> package extensions.

Any idea how I can do that? All I need is he ability to let my customer have my zip files(package files), then they will upload somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just copy folders and paste or merge to new installation directory root folder.Goto admin remove cache and logout.after again login your extension will be there.

Comment: Actually, copying extension package folders and paste onto root... makes sense at all?

Comment: this didn't work for you ?

Comment: AlL I needed was to be able to input my packages files ( package.xml, myextension.xml and myextension-1.0.0.0.1.tgz) and I want my extension to be loaded. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload packaged Magento extension by going to:

`System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager`

then uploading the package under the **Direct package file upload** section.

Furthermore, if you decide not to package your extension, just copy the working file structure of your extension to it's own folder, and you can simply drop your extension files into the working root directory of compatibility Magento installs.  Just be sure your extension file structures are correct.  EX: `app/code/local/MyNamespace/MyExtension` etc.

Comment: Thanks Axel! I cannot see Direct package file upload section in connect. I am using magento 1.4.x and 1.7.x community editions. I am trying the rest.

Comment: AlL I needed was to be able to input my packages files ( package.xml, myextension.xml and myextension-1.0.0.0.1.tgz) and I want my extension to be loaded. But I cant do that nor I can see Direct package file upload section under connect manager

Comment: I installed another magento 1.5.1 version to test my extension. I can see the package upload section. But after uploading, I see "CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed. Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'community' channel."